# If you roll a single dice 7 times, what's the chance that the highest number rolled is 4?

Tags: probability

I tried (4/6)^7, but it doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that 4 appears at least once. The probability will be $(4/6)^7-(3/6)^7$.

Comment: Can you walk me through the process if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: $(4/6)^7$ includes the case 1213111, for example, in which case maximum is 3, not 4. So, we have to subtract the cases where maximum is less than 4, which is $(3/6)^7$.

Comment: $(4/6)^7$ is the probability that all of the dice are less than or equal to 4. So you need to subtract off the probability that all of the dice are strictly less than 4, which is what @Ayaka is saying